# Prove that $\int_a^c f(t)dt - \int_c^b f(t)dt = f(c)(a+b-2c) $, for some $c\in(a,b)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $f$ be a continuous on $[a,b]$ then prove that there exist some $c$ that lies in $(a,b)$ such that
$$\int_a^cf(t)\,dt  - \int_c^b  f(t)\,dt  = f(c)(a+b-2c) $$

and hence prove that 
$\int_a^c f(t)\,dt  - \int_c^b  f(t)\,dt  = n  f(c)(a+b-2c) $ where $n \ge0$

I have been able to prove the first part. but not for general $n$.
I used rolles theorem to prove the first part.
I dont know in which tag to put this question into.

Comment: Maybe this is just math that is beyond me, but are you integrating with respect to $x$ or $t$?

Comment: @Ephraim Seems like the OP has some extra differentials, yes. =)

Comment: with respect to dt...

Comment: Your two integrals are identical, but somehow equal different things. Since the only difference between the top and bottom one is that you added an $n$, the only way that both can be true is if $n=1$. Also, what exactly is $n$ supposed to represent?

Comment: When you say "where $n\ge0$", do you mean "for _some_ $n\ge0$"?  I use "where" to explain the meaning of notation and terminology (for example, "where $n$ is the number of vertices", etc.), but I don't think it's a good idea to use it as a quantifier such as "for some" or "for every".  It's better to spelled out "for some" and "for every" explicitly.  If the reader is puzzling over whether you meant "for some" or "for every", that's effort the reader is spending on something other than understanding what you're trying to say.

Comment: Hm, "this question has an open bounty and can not be closed". I'd vote to close for the "unclear what you are asking" reason.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy : I'd give the reader a chance to respond to comments, where those responses might clarify the question.

Comment: Here n represent all n that are greater than 0..

Comment: I feel like I must be missing something. Isn't the second equation just the first equation with an n added to the left side? If so, we're already done. This would then be true for n = 1 (not any other n, though).

Feeling like I'm missing something - would love it if someone would point out what to me!

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Pick an n and then find a c that makes it true. I had reversed that order.

Answer (score 4):

When $n=0$, it is the Intermediate Value Theorem applied to 
$$
g:x\to \int_a^{x} f -\int_{x}^b f .
$$

Suppose $n>0$.
Let $$d=\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b.$$
If $g (d)=0 $ the inequality is proved for all $n$. 
Suppose this is not the case : there is $c_0\in(a,b)\setminus\{d\}$ where $g(c_0)=0$.

Replacing $f(x)$ by $f(a+b-x)$ if necessary, we may assume $c_0<d$.

Consider the function 
$$
H(x):x\to|a+b-2x|^{1/n}g(x).
$$

Note that $H$ is continuous on both $[a,d]$ and differentiable on $[a,d)$.

As $H(c_0)=H(d)=0$, applying Rolle's Theorem on $[c_0,d]$  we obtain that for some $c\in(c_0,d)$, $H^\prime(c)=0$, that is,
$$
0=-\frac{2}{n}(a+b-2x)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}g(c)+(a+b-2x)^{1/n}\left(2f(c)\right),
$$
in other words,
$$
\int_a^cf -\int_c^b f = nf(c)(a+b-2c).
$$

Comment: Clean and simple :)

Comment: @AthanagorWurlitzer It is not correct that a constant does not change the identity: $g = \int_a^x (f+c) - \int_x^b (f+c) - n(f+c)(a+b-2x) + c(n-1)(a+b-2x)$

Comment: Also with $n\leq 0$ the identity is not true. Take $f=2x$ and $a=0,b=1$ then $c$ should satisfy: $2(2n+1)c^2 - 2nc - 1 = 0$ which has not solutions for say $n=-1$

Comment: @AthanagorWurlitzer Good, now this finally works.

Answer (score 0):

For the case where $n \geq 0$, I am going to reformulate your problem as follows:

Show
$$
\int_a^cf(t) + nf(c)dt = \int_c^bf(t)+nf(c)dt
$$
This is just rearranging some terms, and factoring some things so that everything is inside an integral.  You want to split the brackets on the right side so that you have a $(a-c)$ term and a $(b-c)$ term.  The rest I'll leave as an exercise.  Let me know if you get stuck there, and I can expand a bit further in the comments.

And, believe it or not, that was the hard part.

Now, take each side of this equation separately.  From the assumptions, we know that
$$\int_a^cf(t) + nf(c)dt$$
is a continuous, bounded function of $c$.  Let's call it 
$$
G(c) = \int_a^cf(t) + nf(c)dt.
$$
Now, $G(a) = 0$, and $$G(b) = \int_a^bf(t) + nf(c)dt$$.

Let's call the right hand side 
$$H(c) = \int_c^bf(t)+nf(c)dt.$$
This is also a continuous, bounded function of $c$.  We also know that 
$$H(a) = \int_a^bf(t)+nf(c)dt$$
and $H(b) = 0$.

Using the intermediate value theorem, and the knowledge we've gained about $G(c)$ and $H(c)$, we can conclude there must be some point in the middle where these two functions cross.  That is, there is some point $C$ that makes $G(C) = H(C)$.

Thus, the conclusion holds, that there exists a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$
\int_a^cf(t)dt -\int_c^bf(t)dt = nf(c)(a+b-2c)
$$

Sidenote:  Using Rolle's theorem to solve the first part of this question is pretty slick. However, I don't think there's an equivalent way to do that for the $n > 0$ case.  The IVT looks like the intended solution for both cases.

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: I agree with @OmranKouba. To be more precise: $H(a) = \int_a^b f(t) + n f(a) dt$ not $H(a) = \int_a^b f(t) + n f(c) dt$ as you have written (and the same goes for $G(b)$) so your argument does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Define:
$$
F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t
$$
Then your expression is just:
$$
F(c) - (F(b) - F(c))
  = 2 F(c) - F(b)
$$
If you substitute in your identity, by the fundamental theorem of calculus you get the differential equation:
$$
F'(c)(a + b - 2 c) - 2 F(c) = - F(b)
$$
Its solution is:
$$
F(c) = \frac{F(b) (c - a)}{2 c - a - b}
$$
Differentiate $F$, and you get the only function satifying your identity.

Comment: Which question are you answering?